# Creating a plan repository, but using keyword in constructor body

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a class that needs to access the `planInfo` LINQ variable in every method. Is there any way to do this without removing the using statement and calling `Dispose()` in every method?

The only other way I know to do it is to put the using statement in every method and removing it from the constructor, but that is repeating the where clause in every method but i want it constant.

```
public class PlanRepository
{
    private int _patientId = 0;
    private IQueryable<Plan> planInfo;

    public PlanRepository(int pid)
    {
        if (pid == 0) { UserAccess.RedirectToLogin(); }
        _patientId = pid;

        using (var db = new DbConn())
        {
            planInfo = db.Plans.Where(d => d.PatientId == _patientId);
        }
    }

    public int GetPulse()
    {
        return planInfo.Select(d => d.Pulse).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

This code obviously throws an error that the db connection was closed.

Comment: You should look at IoC container to inject your `DbConn` into the repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just materialize the list in the constructor:

```
planInfo = db.Plans.Where(d => d.PatientId == _patientId).ToList();
```

Now, that caches the data (you won't see any DB updates), but if you didn't want to maintain the DB connection in the first place, that shouldn't be an issue.

With the list materialized, all your other functions can use it with no problem.